# Django Forms - How to make a form inputs type equal to "date"

Tags: python, html, django, forms, date

I am using a django form to create two inputs for date. When created in html the input types are set to type="text". How can I make theses be created with type="date".

forms.py

```
class searchForm(forms.Form):
    datestart = forms.DateField(label="Date Start")
    dateend = forms.DateField(label='Date end')
```

views.py

```py
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = searchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form)
    else:
        form = searchForm()
    return render(request, 'next_launch/search.html',{'form': form})
```

search.html

```
    <form action="search" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}}
        {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can patch the type in the `attrs` of the widget, like:

```
class searchForm(forms.Form):
    datestart = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        label='Date Start'
    )
    dateend = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        label='Date end'
    )
```

If you want to use this more often, you can make your own widget, like:

```
class DateDateField(forms.DateField):
    input_type = 'date'
```

You can then use this as:

```
class searchForm(forms.Form):
    datestart = forms.DateField(widget=DateDateInput, label='Date Start')
    dateend = forms.DateField(widget=DateDateInput, label='Date end')
```

This will render the form like:

```
>>> print(searchForm())
<tr><th><label for="id_datestart">Date Start:</label></th><td><input type="date" name="datestart" required id="id_datestart"></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_dateend">Date end:</label></th><td><input type="date" name="dateend" required id="id_dateend"></td></tr>
```